# solr translating plurals to singular, do not want it to

Tags: java, lucene, solr

i have a field where there are items that are plurals, and used as very specific locators, so i do a solr search type:articles, and it translates it into :

```
<str name="rawquerystring">type:articles
```

type:articles

type:articl

it gets really frustrating, is there a way i can disable this?

Comment: you might want to check about how  stemming and/or  lemmatization are implemented implemented in your solr server.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you are using the StandardAnalyzer to parse your query, which does stemming by default.  Just use a simple tozenizer, or Whitespace Analyzer to parse the query instead.  But you also need to use the same analyzer when you ingest documents into your Lucene (SOLR) index to get correct results.